# How to Read a text file and write it into the excel file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

My Requirement is to read text file, the text file format is

`12345|566437347|34564564|66465^2343|234234|45455|4534643...`

This text file I need to store into the Excel file. In the text file "`^`" is the row separator and "`|`" is the column separator .

Answer (score 1):

You can read the text file into a string and split the string twice:

```
string[] rowArray = textfile.Split('^');
foreach (string row in rowArray )
{
    //excel code

    string[] columnArray = textfile.Split('|');
    foreach (string column in columnArray  )
    {
        //excel code
    }
}
```

First you split the text-file to rows and then split each rows to columns.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [`EPPLus`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to create excel files without having Office installed on the server. Then all you need is a `DataTable` and the `LoadFromDataTable` method.

You need to split the Text by `'^'` to get all lines and each line by `'|'` to get all fields. To get the number of columns of the `DataTable`, you need to find the maximum count of fields in al lines:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\data.txt");
var lines = text.Split('^');
var rows = lines.Select(l => new { Line = l, Fields = l.Split('|') });
var colCount = rows.Max(r => r.Fields.Length);
var tbl = new DataTable();
for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
    tbl.Columns.Add("Column" + i, typeof(string));
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    tbl.Rows.Add().ItemArray = row.Fields;
}
var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\data.xlsx"));
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium6);
pck.Save();
```